# Digital name tag with text change per API

Tags: android, api

I want to give a gift to a friend and I need a digital name tag, but with very specific requirements. And since I have no idea if such a thing exists, I need your help. I have the following requirements:

- The name tag must (as I said) be digital
- It must connect to an Android smartphone
- It has to fetch current data from a web socket by itself via the mobile phone. It would be even better if it has an API that I can send the new value to

Is there such a thing?